# Clicking submit button using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm very newbie at this. I'm trying to login a website using Selenium to make some web scraping but I can't succeed in clicking the submit button.

This is what I'm using:

```
browser.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

And this is the html form code from the web:

```
<div _ngcontent-ihr-c27="" class="form-group">

<button _ngcontent-ihr-c27="" class="btn-fantasy green big" gtm-action="Login_Mail" gtm-category="Interaccion" gtmeventclick="" type="submit"> Iniciar sesión </button>

</div>
```

Any suggestion? Maybe using another attribute in find_element_by_XXX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` And `element_to_be_clickable()` And following xpath option.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn-fantasy green big' and @type='submit'][contains(.,'Iniciar sesión')]"))).click()
```

OR Css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-fantasy.green.big[type='submit']"))).click()
```

You need to imports following.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I succeed using: ``browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()``